# Rails: Couldn't find User with 'id'= Modal dialogue box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I wonder if anyone can shed some light on this for me:

I have a user index page that loads fine.

```
def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

in the view

```
<tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" />
    </td>
    <td id="hidden">
     <%= user.id %>
    </td>
    <td class="ellipsis">
     <%= link_to user.name, edit_user_path(user) %>
    </td>
    <td id="hidden">
     <%= user.projects.count %>
    </td>
    <td>
     <%= user.admin? %>
    </td>
...clipped for brevity
```

The username links to an edit user page as above again all fine...

What I would like to do is have the edit user function in a modal on the index page rather than on a separate edit page. I can get a modal to open on the index page no problem, the js is working fine.

The problem is that when I load the form_for @user (which is already working on my edit page) into the modal I get the error

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

and it refers to this second line in my user controller which I added to index from the edit page.

```
 def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
```

My guess is that this is because the index page loads with no user selected i.e there is no id for the @user variable to refer to... Is that assumption correct?

My form partial is below

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
<% end %>
```

If so how do I get my modal to load so that it can link to the user index in e same way my current page works, without having this no ID issue.

Obviously if I'm misreading this and theres another reason... I'm all ears

Thanks

Comment: There is probably no `params[:id]` on your index page

Comment: You don't get `id` in `params` for `index` action

Comment: Ok guys thx I"ll try thses out see what works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your missing params[:id] is your problem.

To solve this you could "find" the user like this

```
@user = User.where(:id => params[:id]).first||User.new
```

or better as stated by @iceman:

```
@user = User.where(:id => params[:id]).first_or_initialize
```

`@user` will be "new" if no id is given

Comment: This produces another error relating to my form ...First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Comment: Yes, you need to think want you want to do with no id. Probably just add to the line `||User.new`

Comment: Awesome, that worked... thx guys. So just to clarify, as I suspected the reference to @user was causing the error because when the page loaded no user had been selected i.e ID was null? But by adding the || or User.new  this overcomes that and allows the page to load.... but what exactly is User.new doing?

Comment: `.find` with no id will cast an error. `.where.first` will return nil if not found. Your code did not handle `@user == nil`. So with `||User.new` you say: if nil then `@user = User.new`

Comment: Brilliant... thanks for taking the time I appreciate it

Comment: You can also use `where(...).first_or_initialize` and skip the `User.new`

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't find User with 'id'=

This means there is `params[:id]` is `nil`

You don't get `id` in `params` for `index` action change index action to

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not sending a user id in params, so it can't find any user there. If you want to use `form` and `@user` on index you have to send `:id` param to index view. 
default index path looks like

```
/users
```

and default edit path looks like

```
/users/:id/edit
```

Also `find` method is rasing error when it can't find given object. For receiving nill instead of error not found you can use `find_by` or `where().first`

Answer (score 0):

params[:id] is missing in your edit function.

Have you fetched edit page html using js in modal? If yes, then

Add following code in your controller:

```
def index
  @user = User.where(:id => params[:id]).first || User.new
end
```

Comment: In my modal I call <% render form %> and the code you write above is in my index action as the modal is on the index page... is that right? or am I wrong there and it goes in the  edit action as you ave written it

Comment: when you click on edit link, then you have to fetch modal by using ajax and display it on index.html

Comment: Add <%= render form %> in your edit.html.erb which will add modal code in your edit.html.erb file

Comment: Sorry my bad... the button to call the modal is not on the code snip above... the link_to edit_user_path is redundant. Thx for your help ...is resolved with Fallenhero solution